# python - Reformat a dataset into cumulative string sequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-wrangling

I'm using Pandas to wrangle dataframes. I have a dataset of events of users, having one row per event, as below:

| userID | eventID | date | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 2020-01-01 | A |
| 1 | 002 | 2020-01-02 | D |
| 1 | 003 | 2020-01-03 | C |
| 2 | 004 | 2020-01-01 | B |

And I want to build a dataset where that has the users' history as an attribute, and the current event as another attribute, as below:

| userID | history | current_event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | O | A |
| 1 | A | D |
| 1 | A-D | C |
| 2 | O | B |

Where `O` means no history.

I came up with a for loop-based approach, but it gets impractical and super slow as I use it on the bigger dataset. The approach is as below:

```py
inputdf = df.copy()
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['userID', 'history', 'next_event'])

# for loop
for user in inputdf.userID.unique():  # Loop through users
    for i in range(4):    # Loop through events of a user
        subset = inputdf[inputdf.userID== user].sort_values('date').iloc[:i+1]
        if len(subset)==1:  # if first row for a user
            appendrow = pd.DataFrame([{'userID':user, 'history':'O', 'next_event':subset['event'].iloc[0]}])
            final_df = pd.concat([final_df,appendrow], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        else:   # if subsequent row for a user
            grouped = inputdf.sort_values(['userID','date']).iloc[:i].groupby(['userID']).agg({'event': '-'.join}).reset_index()  
            appendrow = pd.DataFrame([{'userID':user, 'history':grouped.event.iloc[0], 'next_event':subset['event'].iloc[-1]}])
            final_df = pd.concat([final_df,appendrow], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates()
final_df.head()
```

Now I want to vectorize the operation. The problem I'm stuck at is that I need to create grouped dataframe till the second last row for a user, and at the same time get the current row event, and put them together. I can't seem to apply a function to every row, as it needs to run in the context of an individual user.

How can I vectorize the operation?

Comment: You can't really vectorize this as you're using strings. A better chance might be to parallelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` in a groupby-apply.

```
from itertools import accumulate

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df.sort_values(["userID", "date"], inplace=True)

t = (
    df.groupby("userID")["event"]
    .apply(lambda x: list(accumulate(x.shift().fillna(""), "{}-{}".format)))
    .reset_index()
    .explode("event")
)
df["history"] = t["event"].str.strip("-").values

print(df)

   userID  eventID       date event history
0       1        1 2020-01-01     A        
1       1        2 2020-01-02     D       A
2       1        3 2020-01-03     C     A-D
3       2        4 2020-01-01     B
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `transform()` and `expanding()`:

```
(df.groupby('userID')['event'].transform(lambda x: ['-'.join(i) for i in x.expanding()])
 .groupby(df['userID']).shift().fillna('O'))
```

Output:

```
0      O
1      A
2    A-D
3      O
```